# Changing the size of slider jumps for mouse click scrolls

Tags: matlab, user-interface, configuration, slider, matlab-figure

When a user click the empty space (the sliding space) of the slider, the slider jumps. Although I have set 31 steps (by setting the slider step size), still there are only 3 jumps when mouse clicking on the empty spaces of the slider which gives big shifts [21 11 1 values on each click].

I want to make smaller shifts/jumps when clicking on the empty space of the slider. The picture explains the empty space as and jumps. I could not find any option to set this functionality in slider's settings.

I have the following settings

```
ihist=[0:0.0005:0.015];
colors=1:0.01:1.25;
handles.output = hObject;
% % Update slider1 value
guidata(hObject, handles);
maxSliderValue = length(ihist);
minSliderValue = 1;
theRange = maxSliderValue - minSliderValue;
steps = [1/theRange, 10/theRange];
set(handles.slider1, 'SliderStep', steps,'value',1);
```

As the total steps are 31 in this case, therefore the slider should not move completely in 3 steps/clicks.

[image]

Comment: What do you want it to do? You said that there are 31 "small" steps, and also specified in the `SliderStep` that the large step (i.e. what happens when clicking at the empty space) is 10 times larger (so `1/30` vs `1/3`) - therefore, clicking on the empty space 3 times is **exactly** what it should take to move it all the way. "Total 3 clicks should be 31" is simply wrong. If you want to change the large step size after every click (e.g. 1/3 -> 1/15 -> 1/30, or any other rule) then just set the `StepSize` in the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have misunderstood how the the [`SliderStep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.control.uicontrol-properties.html#expand_panel_heading_bt6ck7c-1-SliderStep) setting works. Quoting from the documentation:

> Slider step size, specified as the array, `[minorstep majorstep]`. This property controls the magnitude of the slider value change when the user clicks the arrow buttons or the slider trough (slider channel):
>
> - `minorstep` is the fraction of the slider range by which the `Value` property increases or decreases when the user clicks one of the arrow buttons.
> - `majorstep` is the fraction of the slider range by which the `Value` property increases or decreases when the user clicks the slider trough.

In your example, `[minorstep majorstep]` is `[1/theRange, 10/theRange]` (or `[1/30 1/3]` numerically), which means that you need exactly `(1/3)^-1 == 3` clicks to traverse the entire range. If you want `30` clicks to be required (note that you have 1 fewer intervals than slider positions, `|--|--|`), change `majorstep` to `1/theRange` as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, I entirely misunderstood and wasted so much time earlier. Again thanks a lot.